Is there a closed form solution?
Question:
Let $A\in\mathrm{GL}(n,\mathbb{R})[[u]]$ with $A=A^T$, that is a symmetric real matrix, which can not be decomposed into a blockmatrix with $0$ blocks, such that
$$ A = \begin{pmatrix} A_1 & 0 \\ 0 & A_2 \end{pmatrix} $$
is forbidden, but depends on a parameter $u$. Further, let $x$ be a column vector of dimension $n$ over $\mathbb{C}$ and we denote the diagonal matrix by $D(x) = \mathrm{diag}(x)$.
Then, has the equation $$ (A(u) + D(x)^2)x = 0 $$ a closed form solution? Or at least special solutions, that are non-trivial? What if we restrict to tridiagonal matrices or tridiagonal with $A_{i,i+1} = A_{i,i-1} = b$ and $A_{i,i}=a$?
Comment:
I know something about how the Eigenvectors, since $A$ would be Toeplitz for the very special case at the end, but writing out the expression is not nice at all.
Constructing an ODE in $u$, s.t. one can fix $x(u=0)$ in the beginning has also not resulted in anything yet. And a throughout Google search under tags as matrix polynomial decomposition (considering the bracket and similar search phrases) was more than unfruitful. I can reduce it to one polynomial if there exists $(A_{kj})_{k=1,…,n} \not= 0$ and $j$ coming from a permutation of $(1,…,n)$ and know that the expression is invariant under $x\mapsto -x$.
I hope, I was rigorous enough to display the situation.
